# Android Jetpack Compose Scroll to Top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, where is `ScrollToTopButton` coming from? It is mentioned in Google's documentation. Annoyingly, they neglect to mention the package. I have imports of foundation `version 1.2.0-alpha08`; also tried with `1.2.0-beta02` as well as ui  and material (1.1.1). Not found. (yes did do an internet search on the term, came back empty handed).

```kotlin
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:${version}"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:${version}"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
```

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun MessageList(messages: List<Message>) {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()
        // Remember a CoroutineScope to be able to launch
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
        LazyColumn(state = listState) {
            // ...
        }
    
        ScrollToTopButton(
            onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    // Animate scroll to the first item
                    listState.animateScrollToItem(index = 0)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

[Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#control-scroll-position)

Edit: If this is NOT a function they offer, but rather a suggestion to create your own, shame on whoever wrote the documentation, it literally suggests being a function offered by Compose.

Edit 2: Turns out it is a custom function (see the answer). What moved the author of the documentation to write it like this? Why not just put Button? Sigh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not clear from the documentation but you actually have to make your own. For example you can use this:

```
    @Composable
fun ScrollToTopButton(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(bottom = 50.dp), Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { onClick() }, modifier = Modifier
                .shadow(10.dp, shape = CircleShape)
                .clip(shape = CircleShape)
                .size(65.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                contentColor = Color.Green
            )
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp, "arrow up")
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
  val showButton by remember{
    derivedStateOf {
    listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
   }
}
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = showButton,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut(),
            ) {
                ScrollToTopButton(onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        listState.animateScrollToItem(0)
                    }
                })
            }
```

Comment: thanks, I was almost thinking the same, but something told me they couldnt screw up documentation like this (: well I guess they can. its worse than not clear, it literally suggests this being a function they offer.

Comment: @Dmitri check out [this video](https://youtu.be/EOQB8PTLkpY?t=284), so you can find and fix mistake in this answer

Comment: Thanks @PylypDukhov, I have updated my answer with best practice code.

Comment: @PylypDukhov for info I used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhqPpUYJYeQ&t=159s to come up with my first answer.

Comment: I see, I've [left a comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhqPpUYJYeQ&lc=UgwwQi9EmFD5IbWyf914AaABAg) under this video, please thumb it up so the video can be fixed.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for your input! :-)

Comment: @PylypDukhov and Code Poet - you guys amazing, finding and fixing bugs before i even had a chance to try! thanks! works like a charm. One thing perhaps to add to make it clear - scope.launch inside showButton - i used  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()